# Parse.com: Get Pushnotification Message on onPushOpen

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

In my android application I am using the push notifications supplied by Parse.com. I have successfully got this working, however my application has multiple push notifications and different activities should be loaded depending on which push notification has been pressed. I expected to be able to get the message for the push notification from the intent parameter of the onPushOpen, but it seems to be empty? . Does anyone know how I could get the message in the onPushOpen method?.

For some context, I have added my current custom PushReceiver code below.

```
public class PushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Splash.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've upgraded to Parse-1.8.2.

Then you'll also need to do two more things.

1. Add information into your AndroidManifest.xml (within )

   ```
   <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
   <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
           <category android:name="com...ADD_PACKAGE_INFO_HERE..." />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

   <receiver android:name="com..ADD_PACKAGE_INFO_HERE....PushReceiver"
             android:exported="false">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
           <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
           <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. Add this to AndroidManifest.xml outside the  tags
3. Within the cloud code on Parse.com, set the uri of the broadcast to "com....ADD_PACKAGE_INFO_HERE...PushReceiver"

NB: #1 & #2 should be provided for you in the debug trace when you run your android app.

Hope this helps.  I spent hours trying to get this to work and the key for me was updating to 1.8.2.

EDIT:
You should also look at overriding onReceive as well as onPushOpen...that actually gets called on a notification. Good luck.